# Installing python modules to non-default interpreter [Ubuntu 10.04]

Tags: 10.04, python-2.7

- I had python 2.6 as default interpreter.
- I installed 2.7 and I can use it via command line `#>python2.7 ...`
- Now I want to install some modules [PyMongo, MySqlDB etc.] using pip to this new version.
- I can't use sudo apt-get, or pip at commandline since, they install to 2.6 [since, it is default]

Some help solving this conundrum will be appreciated.

Comment: To vote-to-closers: Ubuntu 10.04 server is **not** end-of-life. Desktop is. No software mentioned in the OP is non-LTS, so this is **on-topic**.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek How did you install Python 2.7. Where is it installed?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the source of the given python module and build it with `python2.7`:

```
$ python2.7 setup.py build
$ python2.7 setyp.py install --user --record files.lst
```

(You can then remove the thing with `$ cat files.lst | parallel rm -rf {}`)